# Are there any ways to revoke mvn clean command?

Tags: java, maven

I accidentally use the mvn clean command in java. However, I forget to store relevant files about testing information. It takes a lot of time to retest the project. Are there any ways to revoke this command?

Comment: Simply no. `mvn clean` deleted everything in `target` directory... and what does it mean ` It takes a lot of time to retest the project`?

Comment: I was running mutation testing for a project which requires an amount of time than a single test suite run. The detailed feedback info was in the target directory. However, I happened to run mvn clean command. I will watch out next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not any way to do this through maven.

`mvn clean` deletes the 'target' directory.

You would have to use facilities provided by either your operating system or an external program to to attempt to recover the deleted files in the same way that you would have to if you had manually deleted the files in question.